# Air bubbles in semi liquid chicken sausage

Tags: sausages

I'm facing a problem of existing air bubbles in semi liquid chicken sausage. The bubbles are tiny and mostly formed while mixing to bowl chopper machine. So when I fill the mixture into the casing there observed tiny air bubbles on the sausage. After smoking the tiny bubbles are clearly observed and it is the reason of rejecting much amount while sorting. I used needle for expelling the bubbles but it is a semi liquid mixture so the mixture gets out from that needled hole while knotting manually. 
Can I be helped how to remove or expel the bubbles of chicken sausage.

Comment: difficult to say without knowing what's the process: do you chop the filling and immediately fill the casings? How liquid is the mixture? What's in it besides chicken meat?

Comment: speculating:  if it's very liquid, after grinding, let the mix sit for a few hours and the bubbles will migrate to the surface.  if that won't work, putting the sausage into a mixer on a very slow speed setting for a few minutes will act to push bubbles out of the sausage

Answer (score 3):

Since it’s quite thick and in liquid form, the process inevitably causes air introduced into the product.
if you can’t change your recipe, you might want to consider applying vacuum to the mixture in a chamber, that should help dissipate the bubbles.

Comment: Why can putting the mixture under vacuum introduce botulism? Please explain or provide references.

Comment: I would suggest an edit here.  Vacuuming the mixture is an excellent suggestion for removing the air bubbles.  There is no added botulism risk. All the OP has to do is vacuum, release the vacuum, and transfer the mixture to the casings, proceeding as normal.  I would upvote if you remove the reference to botulism.

Comment: I thought it was an established risk, but I couldn’t find any research to confirm my claim. I removed that part and replaced it with an explanation.

Comment: The application of a vacuum definitively does not cause botulism!  It's really not relevant here.  The short term application of the vacuum is simply to remove air from the mix.  The crafting of the sausage should apply the appropriate techniques to clear any safety hurdles.  So, given the exact question, any reference to botulism is just confusing the issue.  I'm still happy to upvote, once edited appropriately. Just remove your second paragraph.

Comment: I see your point about food safety. Removed it now.